# To clear the QThreadPool?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QThreadPool, and I used a waitforedone() function to makesure all its runnable are finished before I do something else.

But sometimes, instead of waiting all the runnable to be finished I just want to stop, clean and release all the running threads as fast as possible (like if the user cancel his original command).
But there is certainly no clear() method for QThreadPool, what shoud I do now?

Comment: There is no safe way to immediately terminate a thread from the outside. Your best option is to periodically check inside the thread whether a flag is set that it should exit and then exit the run loop.

Comment: But how about clear the queued up runnable in QThreadPool that still hasn't start yet?